# How do include a global's extended reference when creating a class using cache sql storage?

Tags: intersystems-cache

I am creating a class that is mapped to an existing global so it uses cache sql storage not default storage.  This class has extended references (UCKE, SYKE) whose values are set at run-time.  How do I include the extended reference in the sql storage map?  I can't seem to find any Intersystmes documentation about this.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Well, it's not entirely clear what specific problem you are running into.  I just tested a class where I opened Cache Studio, went to the Object Inspector, selected Storage, went down to the row that shows SQL Storage Map, clicked the ellipsis that appear when that row is selected, selected the master map, and for the global name set it to ^[UCKE]MyGlobal.  This generated correct .INT code for SQL statements.

Are you having problems making sure the local variables are set when the SQL runs?  Did I just not understand what you were doing?